# Reshape Pandas Dataframe with duplicate Index

Tags: python, pandas

Current Dataframe:

```
CountryName      IndicatorCode    Year         Value  
Arab World     TX.VAL.MRCH.RS.ZS  1960  1.646954e+01  
Arab World     TX.VAL.MRCH.R1.ZS  1960  2.260207e+00
Arab World     TX.VAL.MRCH.RS.ZS  1961  1.244584e+01
Arab World     TX.VAL.MRCH.R1.ZS  1961  1.860104e+00  
Zimbabwe       DT.DIS.OFFT.CD     2015  8.377700e+07
Zimbabwe       DT.INT.OFFT.CD     2015  2.321300e+07
Zimbabwe       DT.AMT.PROP.CD     2015  6.250000e+05
```

I want to convert each value of IndicatorCode column as different columns and these columns should contain data from the respective rows of Value column.
For example, after doing reshape:

```
CountryName Year TX.VAL.MRCH.RS.ZS TX.VAL.MRCH.R1.ZS  
Arab World  1960 1.646954e+01      2.260207e+00
Arab World  1961 1.244584e+01      1.860104e+00
```

Final Dataframe columns should be:

```
[CountryName, Year, TX.VAL.MRCH.RS.ZS, TX.VAL.MRCH.R1.ZS, DT.DIS.OFFT.CD,DT.INT.OFFT.CD, DT.AMT.PROP.CD]
```

I tried using pivot, but not success. I cannot take Country name as Index also since its not unique.

```
temp = indicators_df.pivot(columns='IndicatorCode',  values='Value')
```

Got `ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pivot_table` which accepts multiple columns as *index*, *values* and *columns*:

```
df.pivot_table("Value", ["CountryName", "Year"], "IndicatorCode").reset_index()
```

[image]

*Some explanation*:

The parameters passed here are by positions, i.e, they are in the order of `values, index, and columns` or:

```
df.pivot_table(values = "Value", index = ["CountryName", "Year"], columns = "IndicatorCode").reset_index()
```

The *values* are what fill the cells of the final data frame, the *index* are the columns that get deduplicated and remain as columns in the result, the *columns* variables are ones that get pivoted to column headers in the result.

Comment: If possible, can you tell what each arguments stand for(A little explanation). I was reading about it now, though not getting it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`set_index` + `unstack`

```
s = df.set_index(['CountryName', 'Year', 'IndicatorCode']).Value
s.unstack().reset_index().rename_axis([None], 1)
```

[image]